# Posição dos pronomes objetos quando há mais do que um verbo em português europeu

Tags: português-europeu, colocação-pronominal

Quando há apenas um verbo, entendo que a posição do pronome objeto é, no caso geral, atrás do verbo:

"O João deu-me a borracha".

No entanto, em alguns casos (perguntas abertas, frases negativas, depois de certas palavras, orações subordinadas relativas), o pronome vem antes do verbo:

"Quando me deu a borracha?", "Não me deu a borracha", "Já me deu a borracha", "A borracha que ele me deu",...

A minha pergunta é a seguinte: O que acontece quando há vários verbos?

Tenho aqui alguns exemplos que encontrei em livros ou em conversas com falantes nativos (portanto não posso garantir que todos estejam corretos), mas não consigo encontrar um conjunto de regras para explicar estes exemplos.

1. "[..] que consegue reproduzir-se em dois dias" (e não "que se consegue reproduzir em dois dias")
2. "[..] que se foram diversificando" (e não "que foram diversificando-se")
3. "[..] que a vais ver/ [..] que vais vê-la"
4. "Não consigo lembrar-me do nome." (e não "Não me consigo lembrar do nome")
5. "Não volto a emprestar-te dinheiro." (e não "Não te volto a emprestar dinheiro.")
6. "por muito que a queira ajudar" (e não "por muito que queira ajudá-la")
7. "Pensava mesmo que te ia conseguir fazer ir para a escola" (e não "Pensava mesmo que ia conseguir-te fazer ir para a escola" ou "Pensava mesmo que ia conseguir fazer-te ir para a escola")
8. "Se quiseres posso te dar o bilhete" (e não "Se quiseres te posso dar o bilhete" ou "Se quiseres posso-te dar o bilhete" ou "Se quiseres posso dar-te o bilhete")
9. "Podiam-me ter dito" (e não "Podiam ter-me dito")
10. "Estas coisas podem-se compor" (e não "Estas coisas podem compor-se")
11. "Podes-me confirmar por favor que [...]" (e não "Podes confirmar-me")

Tenho basicamente duas perguntas.

A)Nos exemplos 1) até 7), estamos em situações em que, se houvesse apenas um verbo, não haveria um clítico, mas quando há mais do que um verbo, pode ou não haver um clítico. Existem regras para estes casos?

B) Quer haja um clítico ou não, que verbo deve ser considerado nas regras (o verbo junto do qual se encontra o pronome, ou à frente, ou atrás na forma clítica), o verbo que não está no infinitivo ou um dos que estão no infinitivo e fornecem mais informações sobre a ação descrita (reproduzir, diversificar, ver, lembrar, emprestar,...)?

Comment: Vê http://alfclul.clul.ul.pt/wochwel/documents/Clíticos_Gramática%20do%20Português_Gulbenkian.pdf o exemplo 2 é diferente (subida é obrigatória com o gerúndio). O 8 é mau exemplo porque é uma oração principal, mas falta uma vírgula. "Posso te dizer" só vale no Brasil.

Comment: @Artefacto Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, no entanto não consigo aceder à página da ligação. É o artigo seguinte? "Martins, A. M. 2013. A posição dos pronomes pessoais clíticos. In. E. Paiva Raposo et al., orgs. Gramática do Português. Lisboa: Fundação Calouste Gulbenkian. 2231-2302."

Comment: É isso. Outro link é https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327095518_Posicao_dos_pronomes_pessoais_cliticos

Comment: Muito obrigado!